# Akka behind HAProxy

Tags: tcp, akka, haproxy, akka-cluster

I have 2 systems: system 1 is running akka and HAProxy, system 2 is running REST components that make a request to akka.

Akka runs on port 4241 on system 1. System 2 is able to connect to System 1 when there is no HAProxy. After I installed HAProxy on system 1, the request from system 2 to system 1 errors out with the logs below:

> ERROR[deal-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] EndpointWriter - dropping
>   message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local
>   recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://akkaSystemName@Server1IP:42431/]] arriving at
>   [akka.tcp://akkaSystemName@Server1IP:42431] inbound addresses are
>   [akka.tcp://akkaSystemName@Server1IP:4241]

HAProxy runs on 42431.

The HAProxy configuration is the following:

```
listen akka_tcp :42431
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        balance leastconn

        server test1 Server1IP:4241 check
        server test2 Server1IP:4241 check
```

The akka configuration is this:

```
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    netty.tcp {

      hostname = "Server1IP"

      port = 4241

      transport-protocol = tcp

      # Sets the send buffer size of the Sockets,
      # set to 0b for platform default
      send-buffer-size = 52428800b

      # Sets the receive buffer size of the Sockets,
      # set to 0b for platform default
      receive-buffer-size = 52428800b

      maximum-frame-size = 52428800b
    }
  }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Updated answer:**

Probably the Akka Remoting is not supposed to work with a Load Balancer. Look at this part of its [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/remoting.html#Peer-to-Peer_vs__Client-Server):

> Akka Remoting is a communication module for connecting actor systems
>   in a peer-to-peer fashion, and it is the foundation for Akka
>   Clustering. The design of remoting is driven by two (related) design
>   decisions:
>
> 1.Communication between involved systems is symmetric: if a system A can connect to a system B then system B must also be able to connect
>   to system A independently.
>
> 2.The role of the communicating systems are symmetric in regards to connection patterns: there is no system that only accepts connections,
>   and there is no system that only initiates connections.
>
> The consequence of these decisions is that it is not possible to
>   safely create pure client-server setups with predefined roles
>   (violates assumption 2) and using setups involving Network Address
>   Translation or **Load Balancers** (violates assumption 1).
>
> For client-server setups it is better to use HTTP or Akka I/O.

For your case it seems reasonable to use Akka HTTP or Akka I/O on system 1 to accept and answer requests from system 2.

---

### **Old answer:**

You have to set the `bind-port` property in the Akka configuration. Here is the quote from the [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#config-akka-remote):

```
# Use this setting to bind a network interface to a different port
# than remoting protocol expects messages at. This may be used
# when running akka nodes in a separated networks (under NATs or docker containers).
# Use 0 if you want a random available port. Examples:
#
# akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = 2552
# akka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-port = 2553
# Network interface will be bound to the 2553 port, but remoting protocol will
# expect messages sent to port 2552.
```

For your ports it should be like that:

```
port = 42431
bind-port = 4241
```

Comment: No it does not work. system 1 does not start on the port 42431. It says port is already used. In the above case by haproxy.BTW I am using akka 2.3.14.

Comment: Yes, the `bind-port` option is not present in version 2.3.14. But it will probably not help you. Look at my updated answer above.